# Is it possible to use MediaTransportControls with FFmpegInterop in UWP?

Tags: ffmpeg, uwp

Is it possible to use the MediaTransportControls? Currently getting the error "Could not decode video" using any MediaTransportControl.

XAML

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayerElement" Source="{Binding VideoSource}" AutoPlay="True" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"/>
```

ViewModel

```
        FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();

        var mediaStreamsource = FFmpegInteropMSS.CreateFFmpegInteropMSSFromStream(stream, false, false).GetMediaStreamSource();

        VideoSource = MediaSource.CreateFromMediaStreamSource(mediaStreamsource);
```

Thanks
Agredo

Comment: I tested your code and can't reproduce this issue. I created a blank uwp app and installed FFmpegInterop.UWP 1.0.4 nuget package. Then using your code snippet to play a .mp4/.webm/.mov media file, they all worked well and didn't receive "Could not decode video" error. What's the type of your media file? What else did you do?

Comment: Maybe I had to be more clear. The video works but using pause, rewind and or other of this buttons cuases the error. I use a mp4 video.